# Delay after displaying splash screen causing problems

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a splash screen that I would like to fade in, while my application goes off and does something, then once complete, if a certain amount of time has elapsed, closes the splash screen and loads the main screen.

The issue Im getting is that while I am looping to check if the amount of time has elapsed, it does not seem to be processing my storyboard to fade in the splash screen.

After reading around I guess I should be starting the splash screen on a different thread?

Heres the code:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MySplashScreen splash = new MySplashScreen();
            splash.Show();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            while (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 10)
            {
            }
            splash.Close();
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Show();

        }

    }
```

The issue is when I add the animation. Its like its not applying any processor to the fade because its stuck in the while loop.

```
<Window x:Class="Splash_Demo.MySplashScreen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="550" Width="900" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" Opacity="0">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:03" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Canvas Height="498" Width="839">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Ash\Downloads\XactSplash.png"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Label Canvas.Left="291" FontFamily="Algerian" Canvas.Top="413" Name="Customer" Height="43" Width="185" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="165" Height="164" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="211" Source="C:\Users\Ash\Downloads\Zerix.bmp" />
        <Label Canvas.Left="191" Canvas.Top="376" FontSize="8" Content="Label" Height="19" Name="lblYear" Width="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're busy-waiting, causing the UI thread to block, and taking a lot of CPU in the process. Instead, set up a timer in your Application_Startup, and open the main window when it expires.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you be able to post a little code sample?

Comment: Also one thing that I should probably have put in my question is that I may want to do other things like preloading dll's when th splash screen is open

Answer (score 1):

While in your 'while' loop you cannot run any animations as your UI thread is blocked (and therefore waiting to run your animation). Try using `DispatcherTimer` instead

Comment: Any reason not to use the standard Timer class as oppose to the DispatchTimer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way and using the API is

```
  SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splashscreen.jpg");
  splash.Show(false);
  splash.Close(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2));
  InitializeComponent();
```